# How can I query a Bigtable column value in BigQuery standard SQL?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-bigtable

I'm trying to query a Bigtable column value with standard SQL in BigQuery:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  default.blah.cell.value
FROM
  mycategory.mytable
WHERE
  rowkey LIKE '123%'
```

I receive the error:

```
Error: Syntax error: Unexpected keyword DEFAULT at [3:3]
```

The above query works fine in legacy SQL, but not in standard SQL.

Selecting the rowkey only **does** work in #standardSQL:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  rowkey
FROM
  mycategory.mytable
WHERE
  rowkey LIKE '123%'
```

How can I select a column value in standard SQL, as the first query in this post is trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `DEFAULT` is a [reserved keyword](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/lexical#reserved-keywords), so you need to escape it using backticks. For example:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  `default`.blah.cell.value
FROM
  mycategory.mytable
WHERE
  rowkey LIKE '123%'
```

Edit: since `cell` is an array type field, you should use the `ARRAY` function if the goal is to read the values from it as an array:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  ARRAY(SELECT value FROM UNNEST(`default`.blah.cell)) AS values
FROM
  mycategory.mytable
WHERE
  rowkey LIKE '123%'
```

You can find more information about [working with arrays](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays) in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks! That took care of `default`! Now I receive this error: `Error: Cannot access field value on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT<timestamp TIMESTAMP, value BYTES>> at [3:25]` Would appreciate any advice

Comment: Added an example of how to express the query. If you have other questions, though, please submit a new StackOverflow post.